# Sorting a list by another list with duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have two lists [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1] and [a, b, c, d, e, f]. I want to reorder elements in the second list according to the permutations that sort the first list. Sorting the first list gives [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3] but there are many possible permutations for the second list to be sorted by the first i.e. [a, d, f, b, e, c], [d, f, a, e, b, c], etc..

How can I generate all of these permutations in an efficient manner in python?

If I just wanted one permutation I could get one by something like this:

```py
sorted_numbers, sorted_letters = list(zip(*[(x, y) for x, y in sorted(zip(numbers, letters))]))
```

Comment: Your one-permutation code does unnecessary things, could just be `sorted_numbers, sorted_letters = zip(*sorted(zip(numbers, letters)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `itertools` to build the Cartesian product of the permutations for each duplicated key:

#### Code

```py
from itertools import chain, permutations, groupby, product
from operator import itemgetter

def all_sorts(numbers, letters):
    return [list(map(itemgetter(1), chain.from_iterable(p))) for p in product(*(permutations(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(zip(numbers, letters)), key=itemgetter(0))))]

print( all_sorts([1,2,3,1,2,1], 'abcdef') )
# [['a', 'd', 'f', 'b', 'e', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'f', 'e', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'f', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c'], ['a', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'a', 'f', 'b', 'e', 'c'], ['d', 'a', 'f', 'e', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'c'], ['d', 'f', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'c'], ['f', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c'], ['f', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'c'], ['f', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'c'], ['f', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'c']]
```

This approach is optimal in the sense that it generates the solutions directly, rather that filtering them from a huge list of candidates. With the given example list of size 6, it generates only 12 solutions, rather than filtering through all 720 permutations of a list of size 6.

#### How it works:

First we sort and group by key, using `sorted` and `itertools.groupby`. Note `operator.itemgetter(0)` is the same as `lambda t: t[0]`.

```py
>>> [list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(zip(numbers, letters)), key=itemgetter(0))]
[[(1, 'a'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'f')],
 [(2, 'b'), (2, 'e')],
 [(3, 'c')]]
```

Then we generate the possible permutations of every key, using `itertools.permutation` on every group.

```py
>>> [list(permutations(g)) for _,g in groupby(sorted(zip(numbers, letters)), key=itemgetter(0))]
[[((1, 'a'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'f')), ((1, 'a'), (1, 'f'), (1, 'd')), ((1, 'd'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'f')), ((1, 'd'), (1, 'f'), (1, 'a')), ((1, 'f'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'd')), ((1, 'f'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'a'))],
 [((2, 'b'), (2, 'e')), ((2, 'e'), (2, 'b'))],
 [((3, 'c'),)]]
```

Then we build the Cartesian product of these lists of permutations, using `itertools.product`; and we rebuild a list from each tuple in the Cartesian product, using `itertools.chain` to concatenate. Fially we "undecorate", discarding the keys and keeping only the letters, which I did with `map(itemgetter(1), ...)` but could have equivalently done with a list comprehension `[t[1] for t in ...]`.

```py
>>> [list(map(itemgetter(1), chain.from_iterable(p))) for p in product(*(permutations(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(zip(numbers, letters)), key=itemgetter(0))))]
[['a', 'd', 'f', 'b', 'e', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'f', 'e', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'f', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c'], ['a', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'a', 'f', 'b', 'e', 'c'], ['d', 'a', 'f', 'e', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'c'], ['d', 'f', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'c'], ['f', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c'], ['f', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'c'], ['f', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'c'], ['f', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 2):

If the size of the lists is not too large you could just use a **[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)** to filter all the permutations with a helper function:

```py
from itertools import permutations


def is_valid_ordering(perm: str, ch_to_order: dict) -> bool:
    if not perm or len(perm) <= 1:
        return True
    for ch1, ch2 in zip(perm[:-1], perm[1:]):
        if ch_to_order[ch1] > ch_to_order[ch2]:
            return False
    return True


lst_1 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
lst_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
ch_to_order = {ch: o for ch, o in zip(lst_2, lst_1)}
valid_permutations = [
    list(p) for p in permutations(lst_2)
    if is_valid_ordering(p, ch_to_order)
]
for valid_perm in valid_permutations:
    print(valid_perm)
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'd', 'f', 'b', 'e', 'c']
['a', 'd', 'f', 'e', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'f', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c']
['a', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'c']
['d', 'a', 'f', 'b', 'e', 'c']
['d', 'a', 'f', 'e', 'b', 'c']
['d', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'c']
['d', 'f', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'c']
['f', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c']
['f', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'c']
['f', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'c']
['f', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'c']
```

---

Alternatively if the lists are large and therefore efficiency is important, you could construct only the valid orderings (see [Stef's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70126643/6328256) for an even better approach than below):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import permutations, product
from iteration_utilities import flatten

lst_1 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
lst_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
equivalent_chars = defaultdict(list)
for o, ch in zip(lst_1, lst_2):
    equivalent_chars[o].append(ch)
equivalent_char_groups = [g for o, g in sorted(equivalent_chars.items())]
all_group_permutations = [[list(p) for p in permutations(group)]
                          for group in equivalent_char_groups]
valid_permutations = [
    list(flatten(p)) for p in product(*all_group_permutations)
]
for valid_perm in valid_permutations:
    print(valid_perm)
```

Comment: If the list has a large length `n` and only a small number of duplicates, the method you suggest will have to examine all `n!` permutations of the list instead of only the small number of solutions.

Comment: Valid point but I should have said that in all cases `n` will be < 10. It appears to work and catch the edge case I had but let me know if there's a more efficient approach! Thanks!

Comment: Regarding *"see Stef's answer for an even better approach than below"*; I wouldn't call my answer better. The only two differences are: 1) I group with `groupby` whereas you group with `defaultdict`; 2) You split the code into several simple lines whereas I went crazy with an illegible one-liner. Since the list needs to be sorted anyway, the `groupby` and `dict` approaches to grouping are comparable in efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation without filtering:

```
from itertools import product, permutations, chain

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

grouper = {}
for number, letter in zip(numbers, letters):
    grouper.setdefault(number, []).append(letter)
groups = [grouper[number] for number in sorted(grouper)]
for prod in product(*map(permutations, groups)):
    print(list(chain.from_iterable(prod)))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'd', 'f', 'b', 'e', 'c']
['a', 'd', 'f', 'e', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'f', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c']
['a', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'c']
['d', 'a', 'f', 'b', 'e', 'c']
['d', 'a', 'f', 'e', 'b', 'c']
['d', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'c']
['d', 'f', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'c']
['f', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c']
['f', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'c']
['f', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'c']
['f', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'c']
```

It first groups the letters by their numbers, using a dict:

```
grouper = {1: ['a', 'd', 'f'], 2: ['b', 'e'], 3: ['c']}
```

Then it sorts the numbers and extracts their letter groups:

```
groups = [['a', 'd', 'f'], ['b', 'e'], ['c']]
```

Then just permute each group and build and chain the products.